# Trouble playing a video downloaded from firebase storage via url in conjunction with Angular 2+

Tags: angular, firebase, video-streaming

--.TS-FILE--
`this.fileRef = this.afs.ref('images/mrbrianhewitt@gmail.com/dfsf/delta.mpg') this.fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe( data => { this.tmpUrl = data; })`
--.HTML FILE--

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
```

`<source src="{{tmpTest}}" type="video/mpeg"></video>`

Above are my ts and html set up. Every time I try to enter the url manually in my client browser, it simply downloads the mp4 video.  I would like to have the video play in the browser.  Am I approaching this situation the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs only those format are supported:

video/mp4, video/webm, video/ogg

Comment: It works in Safari, but not in chrome. I am testing with an mp4 file as you suggested. Any ideas? @RazRonen